# Ошибка синтаксиса при использовании команды принт

Tags: python, синтаксис

```py
def F(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return n
    if n > 2:
        return 3 * F(n - 1) - F(n - 2)
print(f(6))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Версия питона 3.12(помощь нужна именно по этой)

Comment: Если вы пытаетесь это вводить в интерактивную консоль, то не забывайте жмать Enter второй раз для закрытия блока def

Comment: Точно синтаксиса? Мне вот видится что имена `f` и `F` разные

Comment: в этом коде нет синтаксической ошибки

Comment: Интересно, может код не полный, но ведь как-то же ТС получил SyntaxError 

Answer (score 2):

```
def F(n):
```

Функция F, а вызов f:

```
print(f(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

`print(f(6))`

Нужно

`print(F(6))`

Даже сам питон говорит об этом `Do you mean 'F'?`